# Jquery Ajax post animation during ajax process?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, loading-image

I do ajax post on my mvc app when dropdown change.

```
$(function () {
    $('#meters').change(function () {
        var analizor_id = $(this).val();
        if (analizor_id && analizor_id != '') {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("AnalizorInfoPartial", "Enerji")',
                type: 'GET',
                cache: false,
                data: { analizor_id: analizor_id },
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#TableAnalizorInfo').html(result);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

DropDown

```
@Html.DropDownList("sno", new SelectList(Model, "sno", "AnalizorAdi"), "-- Analizör Seçiniz --", new { id = "meters" })
```

Can I show a loading image or anything else during ajax process? (between begin - finish event) and Code example?

**EDIT**

Can I use like this?

```
success: function (result) {
    $('#TableAnalizorInfo').html(result);
}
begin:function(){ 
    //show image
}
complete:function(){ 
    //hide image
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course, the events you are looking for are `beforeSend` and `complete`:

```
if (analizor_id && analizor_id != '') {
     $.ajax({
         url: '@Url.Action("AnalizorInfoPartial", "Enerji")',
         type: 'GET',
         cache: false,
         beforeSend: function() {
             // Show your spinner
         }, 
         complete: function() {
             // Hide your spinner
         },
         data: { analizor_id: analizor_id },
         success: function (result) {
            $('#TableAnalizorInfo').html(result);
        }
    });
}
```

or you could do it globally for all AJAX requests on the page using [global AJAX event handlers](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/):

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function() {
    // Show your spinner
}).ajaxComplete(function() {
    // Hide your spinner
});
```